# How to bind to another attribute from within a structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have created a **structural** `SpinnerDirective` that I use like this:

```html
<div *spinner="'spinner1'" spinnerMessage="Loading many things...">
  <p>Hide this while loading...</p>
</div>
```

The code of the directive looks like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[spinner]'
})
export class SpinnerDirective {
  private _defaultMessage = 'Loading...';

  @Input('spinner') spinnerName: string;

  @Input('spinnerMessage') set message(messageStr: string){
    console.log('setting message of', messageStr);
    this._defaultMessage = messageStr || this._defaultMessage;
  }

  // ...
}
```

PROBLEM: The setter method (`set message`) never gets called.

I suspect this is because Angular "desugars" my template as follows:

```html
<template [spinner]="'spinner1'">
  <div spinnerMessage="Loading many things...">
    <p>Hide this while loading...</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I still don't know how to access `spinnerMessage` from within the directive. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The structural directive syntax should look like:

```html
<div *spinner="'spinner1'; message: 'Loading many things...'">
  <p>Hide this while loading...</p>
</div>
```